# Rails query interface: selecting rows in database where any of the JSON array's values match a certain criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql, qsqlquery

Database info:

- Database: PostgresSQL
- Table name: publishing_rules
- Column name: menu_items
- Column format: JSON
- Example column value: {"items":[{"id":1,"title":"dfgdfg"},{"id":2,"title":"sdf"}]}

I need to gather all columns which have at least one item  with an id equal to my value. So far I've come up with this:

```
    id = 1
    items = PublishingRule.where("menu_items #> '{items,0}' ->> 'id' = ?", id.to_s)
```

However this code only acquires columns with items array first value matching my criteria. I need to modify my code to something similar to:

```
    items = PublishingRule.where("menu_items #> '{items, ANY}' ->> 'id' = ?", id.to_s)
```

or

```
    id = 1
    items = PublishingRule.where("menu_items #> '{items.map}' ->> 'id' = ?", id.to_s)
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `items` is *array* at given example you can't work it out using only operators. You need to use `jsonb_array_elements()` in order to look into that.

Here's SQL query example to meet your requirement:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    publishing_rules
WHERE   EXISTS (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    jsonb_array_elements( menu_items -> 'items' )
            WHERE   value ->> 'id' = '2'
            LIMIT   1
        );
```

So, using within `WHERE EXISTS` lookup into the array does the trick.

Comment: This query throws json_arraay_elements does not exist error in my db. Either way I took a different approach to this problem, by modifying my JSON structure. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was using `jsonb_array_elements` but if your data storage type is JSON not JSONB then you need to use `json_array_elements` instead.